# Cookie authorization works only for Scaffolded Identity Area

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm working on a project that uses IdentityServer for authentication. The backend app consists of:

- few Razor pages that are used for admin related tasks. User is supposed to be authorized with cookies.
- mobile app. User is supposed to be authorized with JWT token.

[image]

As long as I'm trying to access scaffolded Pages from Identity/Pages/Account/* area (as seen on the screenshot) like Login.cshtml or Register.cshtml, the identity cookie is used correctly and I'm able to see User Claims and use [Authorize] attribute without any problems.

But after creating new set of Razor Pages inside Pages/Admin path, I noticed the cookie is not used even though it's provided in the Request. I think this happens because by default, IdentityServerJwt scheme is used for authorization.

I managed to get this working by specyfing following attribute for my newly created pages:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Identity.Application")]
```

The cookie is then correctly used to authorize the user but this is not ideal because I'm not able to read user's claims on pages that doesn't necessarily require user authentication as these users no longer can access it because of Authorize attribute.

What can I do in order to force my pages to use cookie authorization without breaking JWT authorization for my API?

The configuration of a backend app is as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider descriptionProvider, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthorization();
}
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
    
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

    services.AddTransient<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddIdentityServerJwt();

    return services;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think you should put IdentityServer on its own service instance, and keep ASP.NET Identity and your client applications separately. Because otherwise it will be very complex to understand and troubleshoot.  When you put it all in the same service, it will be a big mess. :-)

For example there will be many cookies involved, IdentityServer issues its own cookies and your client/ASP.NET Identity issues its own cookie.